# Hibernate Search: Define dynamically searchable classes

Tags: hibernate, lucene, hibernate-search

The code below works fine, however I need to extend it to support from two classes (UserEnt and BookEnt) to 40 classes. To improve performance, I will allow the user to select the classes to search, meaning that the classes in the method createFullTextQuery should be declared dynamically depending on the selection. Is this possible? Otherwise I will have to declare the 40 classes in createFullTextQuery.

```
    // LUCENE SEARCH
    String[] fields = {"firstName", "lastName", "name"};
    QueryParser parser = new MultiFieldQueryParser( Version.LUCENE_34,
     fields, new StandardAnalyzer(Version.LUCENE_34)); 

    org.apache.lucene.search.Query luceneQuery = null; 
    try { 
     luceneQuery = parser.parse(s); 
    } 
    catch (ParseException e) { 
        throw new RuntimeException("Unable to parse query: " + s, e); 
    }

    // HIBERNATE SEARCH WRAP

    FullTextEntityManager ftEm = Search.getFullTextEntityManager(em); 
    javax.persistence.Query query = ftEm.createFullTextQuery(luceneQuery, 
                                            UserEnt.class, BookEnt.class);

    List <?> results = query.getResultList();

    System.out.println("Records found:"+results.size());
```

Answer (score 1):

The method [createFullTextQuery(..)](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/search/5.0/api/org/hibernate/search/jpa/FullTextEntityManager.html#createFullTextQuery(org.apache.lucene.search.Query,%20java.lang.Class...)) takes a first mandatory parameter, and then an **optional** varargs parameter to list all types you want to search for.

You could simply omit listing the types there, to have it target all known indexed entities.

```
FullTextEntityManager ftEm = Search.getFullTextEntityManager(em); 
javax.persistence.Query query = ftEm.createFullTextQuery(luceneQuery);
```

Explicitly listing the types is a form of filtering, but you could also roll your own custom [FullTextFilter](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/search/5.0/reference/en-US/html_single/#query-filter) to restrict the results on some other criteria, and still target all known types to not need to list them.